# why iframe is slow to load the content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I have created CEF base desktop application, where I want to show two tabs ( login, iframeView), clicking on iframeView tab should load the iframe and show the content accordingly.
I use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router library to route the page.

but the problem here is, whenever we click on the second tab which has iframe, iframe takes time to load the content, what I want is, it should show iframe content immediately as soon as user click on tab, if I remove iframe code and add any other tags, it show the content quickly,

we have set Cache-Control: public, max-age=21600 in response header of URL https://example.com to get content loaded from cache but still it takes a time to load the content.
I tried by adding below Iframe code in main DOM and then tried to copy the same Iframe when the user clicks on the second tab but still, it takes the time to load the content.

is there any way to load the iframe content quickly?
Why is iframe slow?

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
   [...]
   <body ng-app="name" ng-controller="mainController" ng-init="init()" ui-
 view>
 </body>
 </html>
```

mainController

```
.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $state, session, [...]) {
$scope.tabClick = function () {
                $state.go('iframeView');
    });
};
```

})

EDIT: Route definitions

```
 .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
$stateProvider
    .state('iframeView', {
        url: '/iframeView',
         template: '<frame-view layout flex></frame-view>'
    })
   })
```

HTML of iframe-view

```
  <iframe id="myIframe" src="https://example.com" style="width500px;height:500px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Only way to preload the iframe is to have it already existing in the main page. It is a complete window that loads a whole page which takes time. You can hide it and position it inside second tab (state) as needed

Comment: Earlier I tried by adding it to main index.html and when user clicks on second tab, I tried to append same Iframe to second tab but it doesn't help 
  <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
    <body ng-app="name" ng-controller="mainController" ng-init="init()" ui-view>
    iframe id="tempIframe" src="https://example.com" style="width500px;height:500px"></iframe>
</body></html>
 below is directive of second tab

Comment: app.directive("frameView", function() {
    return {
        template : "<div>second tab Iframe content</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {
        // find the Iframe tag which is in main DOM
        var frame = angular.element($document[0].querySelector('#tempIframe'));
        // append it to second tab
        element.append(frame); ); };});

Comment: But when you append it , it has to completely load page again. Sure the assets will be cached but all the script has to run again and if that script makes ajax calls it will still take time. Changing it's position or visibility instead would mean not having to do all that again